# Can I extend 22 gauge stranded wire with 18?

Tags: electrical, wiring, low-voltage, splicing

I am doing some manually splicing of some outdoor wire and I wanted to know if I could:

Extend 22 gauge stranded wire with 18 gauge stranded wire then back to 22 gauge stranded. (22 -> 18 -> 22)

Everything is rated for the 22 gauge stranded, I am strictly using the 18 to extend the wire.

As long as I don't exceed the total load for the 22 gauge stranded is this safe? Are there any risks or concerns in extending with a higher gauge than going back down to the original.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's perfectly fine. A comparable situation with 120V wiring is where a 15A circuit has 14 AWG wiring and is extended using 12 AWG wiring. Larger is always fine.

In some cases, this is done deliberately to avoid voltage drop. With 120V this generally applies only with very long wires (> 100'). You can calculate the voltage drop based on the type of wire, voltage and current [using a calculator such as this one](https://www.southwire.com/calculator-vdrop).

In other cases this is done for convenience - e.g., to use whatever wire you have on hand or to stock fewer sizes of wire.

The only time this causes a problem is if the larger wire size is too large for inexpensive connections (wire nuts or Wago or similar) or too large to fit on a breaker or panel lugs. None of which is an issue with low-voltage 18 AWG vs. 22 AWG.

Comment: That makes perfect sense - thanks for the answer and clarity